# Badblocks - Python3 - Capture output and error correctly with live output

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to capture the output from badblocks using python however, the command seems to block.

Having a bit of a struggle with due to the way that badblocks updates its progress...

I logged the output to a text file, which produced output like so...

```
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)  0.45% done, 0:01 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
```

The command uses `\r` carriage returns to overwrite the output in the terminal, it is noted also, that badblocks appears to kick its output to stderr...

Any ideas/advice? :)

```
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            f"badblocks -s {self.device.dut}".split(),
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            universal_newlines=True,
            start_new_session=True,
            text=True
        )

        while True:
            stdout_line = process.stdout.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
            stderr_line = process.stderr.readline().rstrip('\r\n')

            if stdout_line:
                print(f"Standard Output: {stdout_line}")

            if stderr_line:
                print(f"Standard Error: {stderr_line}")

            if process.poll() is not None and stdout_line == "" and stderr_line == "":
                break

        # Describes the processing after the process ends.
        print("Process finished with return code:", process.returncode)
```

I tried logging to a text file, which logged the following...

[output in logfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vOay.png)